# How to express this statement better - ill toward

Tags: word-choice, expressions

We have this paragraph here:

> The forum is here for collectors of all persuasions, so unless you're
>   in a thread specifically geared towards comparison/discussion, **keep
>   your ill toward comments out of the thread**. Note that there is a
>   difference between having a reasonable argument in the correct thread
>   and trolling.

How can we express the bolded part better - it just doesn't sound right!

Comment: What *are* you trying to say? Off-topic comments? Rude comments? Explain it to me like I'm five years old, and then just go ahead and use that simple wording.

Comment: To keep it as close to the original as possible, you could say "keep your ill-willed comments out of the thread."  Have a nice day.

Comment: Are we even sure this _is_ the original rather than a miscopy?

Comment: I simply assumed he was trying to modify "untoward" with a new prefix "illtoward".   This may be a false assumption, but I worked with what was given.  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The forum is here for collectors of all persuasions, so unless you're
>   in a thread specifically geared towards comparison/discussion, **keep
>   your [uncalled-for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncalled-for) comments out of the thread**. Note that there is a
>   difference between having a reasonable argument in the correct thread
>   and trolling.

Also, consider [unbefitting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unbefitting).

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean ***untoward***.

> adjective
> Unexpected and inappropriate or inconvenient:
> *both tried to behave as if nothing untoward had happened*
> *untoward remarks*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/untoward)

Answer (score 0):

This forum's mission is to promote, and educate collectors of all persuasions.  Please be respectful, and avoid contemptuous interactions with the notable exception of spirited debates in the comparison/discussion threads.

Please note, the administrators will make the final judgement on controversial, inappropriate, or trolling comments and repeated misuse of (name of site) will be subject to a permanent ban.